# Understating how assets in Rails 4 work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

The compiled assets are written to pubic/assets:

```
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:00.987988 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white-62b67d9edee3db90d18833087f848d6e.png
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:01.037698 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-c806376f05e4ccabe2c5315a8e95667c.png
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:01.053630 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/marketing/slider-base/slide-01-b85e542137a02bedd6c30dede873ef1e.jpg
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:01.066371 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/marketing/slider-base/slide-02-e5106e911d8a0289bfaf2ac64308a640.jpg
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:01.077879 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/marketing/slider-base/slide-03-990dccbed4c70f0118b7d30d98094811.jpg
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:01.965560 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/application-98713f9763bccfd6bc05dae422d3e242.js
I, [2013-07-21T02:16:02.068469 #13881]  INFO -- : Writing /home/jpereira/dev/saleshub/public/assets/application-a40c2cd9b0f20b2a7f3b62d45159fbb3.css
```

Then, I start the application in production, with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-07-21 02:20:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-07-21 02:20:49] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2013-07-21 02:20:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13903 port=3000
```

But the rendered pages, don't look for the precompiled asses. In the rendered templates I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>App Home Pagetitle>

  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/marketing.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/marketing.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="8XQYBZWrTxmfdGvQYCK0JwQDfr2pt8si+FjW4a30SsA=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The template is the following:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title App Home Page
    =yield(:head)
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller]
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    =flash_messages(flash)
    = yield
```

My production.rb is as follows:

```
WebApp::Application.configure do 
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

end

What I need to configure to have stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag pick the right assets location on production?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I just finished writing a similar question, when yours came up in the related sidebar :)

I found a [blog](http://railsblog.kieser.net/2013/08/rails4-phusion-passenger-asset-pipeline.html) that suggests this is a bug, and is inexplicably mitigated by setting

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

In the end I [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18608732/195061).

Comment: Thanks for this. I had no idea this was a problem in Rails4.

Answer (score 1):

If your creating assets in subfolders you need to prefix your files with the path to the file:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( admin/admin.css admin/admin.js )`. You'l find this command commented out in environments/production.rb

setting `config.assets.compile = true` is a bad idea, its slow and not necessary.

Once you've added your custom assets to config.assets.precompile, run:
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` in the terminal to compile the assets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to look at the following: that states: [Edge Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile)

> In Rails 4.0, precompiling assets no longer automatically copies non-JS/CSS assets from vendor/assets and lib/assets. Rails application and engine developers should put these assets in app/assets or configure config.assets.precompile.

Further to this I believe you can do specify your JS files by doing the following in your `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( 'application.js', 'application.css',
                                 #specify CSS or JS files inside here! )
```

Then execute:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`