# files produced by asset:precompile don't match urls generated by stylesheet_link_tag (missing digest) in minimal rails 4 site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `Ruby 2.0.0-p247` and `Rails 4.0.0`

If I make a minimal Rails 4 site like this:

```
rails new minimal
cd minimal
rails generate controller home index
tee config/routes.rb <<EOF
Minimal::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
EOF
```

Then precompile the assets with

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It generates assets like:

```
I, [2013-09-04T17:05:36.992951 #3549]  INFO -- : Writing /WORKINGDIR/minimal/public/assets/application-723d1be6cc741a3aabb1cec24276d681.js
I, [2013-09-04T17:05:37.052303 #3549]  INFO -- : Writing /WORKINGDIR/minimal/public/assets/application-f1a14051f17824976271b9c0460232f0.css
```

But if I start the server in production mode, with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

The generated URLs in the HTML don't point at the precompiled files:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

I would expect, rather:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="assets/application-f1a14051f17824976271b9c0460232f0.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-723d1be6cc741a3aabb1cec24276d681.js"></script>
```

The default `config/environments/production.rb` settings say to use digests:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

But it seems to be selectively ignored?

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

I just tested this in Rails 4.2.3 and this appears to be fixed, however we need to hand a few more environment variables into the `rails s` command to start in production mode:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rake secret) RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Answer (score 12):

While I was writing up this question I came across this blog post which suggests it is a bug.

http://railsblog.kieser.net/2013/08/rails4-phusion-passenger-asset-pipeline.html

Of the various suggestions, just setting the compilation fallback true...

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

seems to be sufficient to kick Rails in to generating appropriately digested URLs:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-f1a14051f17824976271b9c0460232f0.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-723d1be6cc741a3aabb1cec24276d681.js"></script>
```

The other suggestion, explicitly setting RAILS_ENV and RAILS_GROUPS seemed to produce different digest strings on the precompiled files, but they always seem to match up with the generated HTML regardless.

Comment: I usually set RAILS_ENV=production. This seems to be a regression from 3.2.x :(

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true` will have performance issues in production, I think

Comment: @Johann if yuou are still doing `rake assets:precompile` when you deploy (as you would if `config.assets.compile` were `false`) the live recompilation code should never actually be hit (since it will always see the precompiled versions and serve them up).

Comment: @pix - unless for some reason some assets were not getting compiled with the precompile. Ultimately, if config.assets.compile = true is helping you in production, then it's at the cost of performance.

My application had MASSIVE delay issues (+35 second view rendering!!) in production thanks to config.assets.compile = true. Turns out rails was only precompiling application.css and application.js and compiled the others on the fly (causing the delay). 

My solution was this: config.assets.precompile += %w( application*.css application*.js application*.scss )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve asset links not including the digest by bumping the asset version number.

```
     # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
-    config.assets.version = '1.0'
+    config.assets.version = '2.0'
```

You'll find this either in `config/application.rb` if you're upgrading or in the newer location `config/initializers/asset.rb`